# Remove link to leafletjs.com in attribution control in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, offline

I will use the leaflet for a display showing a historical map of the history museum. It works on a local network that is not connected to the Internet, and visitors can manipulate the map with a stylus to learn about historical matters.

[image]

Leaflet will automatically generate a link to leafletjs.com in the attribution.
However, this link does not work because it is on a local network, and if a visitor accidentally touches it with a stylus, an inaccessible error screen will appear, confusing the visitor.

Is it possible to suppress this link to leafletjs.com?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Map object (let's say it's `map`) has property `map.attributionControl` which points to default map attribution control, where so called prefix is text `Leaflet` with a link to the Leaflet home page.

Attribution control prefix can be changed with the `.setPrefix` method (see https://leafletjs.com/reference.html#control-attribution-option). So to change prefix to text `Leaflet` without the link, the code could look like this:

```
map.attributionControl.setPrefix('Leaflet');
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!!